# How to redirect back to specific URL in query string at facebook login api NodeJs

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing authentication with Facebook account in my app and redirect to specific URL after authentication is successfully. But the problem is how to redirect back to original URL defined in query string.

here is URL when I click on Login button

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&client_id=[CLIENT_ID]

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('facebook', function (err, user) {
        /* I want to redirect back */
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.redirect(redirectUrl + "?error=social_login_failed");
            } else {
                res.redirect(redirectUrl);
            }
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: You mean, getting the original url from where the request was initiated?

Comment: @HungryMind yap, sure.

Comment: How about res.redirect('redirectUrl + ?fromUrl= +req.originalUrl); and handling accordingly?